# console application to check for 7 folders and delete the oldest one if i have more than 7

Tags: c#

I need to come out with a console application to check for 7 `SASE Lab Tools` folders inside `C:\Work\Build`.

These different `SASE lab Tools` folders are date stamped

An example is shown below:

1. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools`
2. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.01052011`
3. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.02052011`
4. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.03052011`
5. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.04052011`
6. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.05052011`
7. `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.06052011`

where the date stamp format is `ddMMyyyy`

so if for example i have `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.07052011` now(8th and latest one) how do i make sure that i can delete the `C:\Work\Build\SASE Lab Tools.01052011` folder? I need to force delete this folder too.. as there are readonly files inside it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you sort them then `Skip` 7 and then delete the remainder?

```
static string path = @"C:\Work\Build";

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "SASE Lab Tools.*");

    // Remove after testing
    foreach(var file in files)
        Console.WriteLine(file);

    Console.WriteLine("");

    foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7))
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    // END Remove after testing

    foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7))
        File.Delete(file);
}
```

Comment: yeah, dumpp them into List<string> and then sort and remove first 7 from the index, loop through the rest and try to delete them